# Pickle file is not recognized in docker

Tags: docker

I have a python3 application with a few pickle files as an input. The application works, but can't read the pickle files. I checked the pickle files are copied to the container.
Reading CSV files seems ok.

I tried to create a new test pickle file inside the container but didn't work.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "app/main.py" ]
```

Logs

```
generating values, it will take some time...
start simulation
step 1, time spent: 0.38000479599998016
step 2, time spent: 0.4123095479999961
step 3, time spent: 0.4407059019999906
step 4, time spent: 0.43041304799999125
step 5, time spent: 0.4444566669999972
step 6, time spent: 0.45184545699999035
step 7, time spent: 0.4395601109999916
step 8, time spent: 0.462191746999963
step 9, time spent: 0.47820707500000026
step 10, time spent: 0.44471388899995645
data stored
```

At generating values, it should read pickle files already there but didn't.

Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Would you mind editing your post and showing us your code?

Comment: Hi, it is a large code. The issue is with the docker container not with the code itself. The pickle files (.p), why docker container can't see them?

Comment: Hey, could you share the docker container logs?

Comment: I updated the post, please check. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

First of all docker can't store the pickle file as of my knowledge.. U have to store it in cloud and use in u r project.